# How can I get crash log of other apps using Swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, logging, crash

So I hope to get crash log of all app in my phone.

Although I find the many library, there are only get the log in the my app, but I want to get all app log, like to Organizer window of Xcode.

Do you know any solution?

Comment: Now, I develop the software test assistant app.
But i don't deploy in the app store, only using some people.
So i hope to get crash log of all app in my phone.

Although i find the many library, there are only get the log in the my app, but i want to get all app log, like to organizer of X code.

do you know this solution?

Comment: Are you using TestFlight to deploy?

Comment: use [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics).

Comment: @Michael yes, i deploy using "TestFlight" or enterprise

Comment: @AnuragSharma, Crashlytics Only get crash log of developed by me

Comment: @kingsSky You don't have any access to get crash logs of the apps not developed by you!

Comment: @AnuragSharma thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics will help for all the apps developed by you, but If you are looking for crashes of all apps in your phone, but these apps are not developed by you, I think that the only way to get detail crashes logs is by organizer->devices, as you say. :S